# C# WCF - (407) Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy

We are trying to establish WCF service connection using `ConfigurationChannelFactory`.

This is the sample code.

```
private void OpenGateWayServiceConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                string gateWayEndPointAddress = "URI";    
                String physicalfilePath = "GateWayService.config"

                ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();                     

                fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = physicalfilePath;
                Configuration newConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

               _channelFactory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMyContract>(
                        "GateWayServiceEndPoint",
                        newConfiguration,
                        new EndpointAddress(gateWayEndPointAddress));

                ((BasicHttpBinding)_channelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
                ((BasicHttpBinding)_channelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).ProxyAddress = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy(new Uri(gateWayEndPointAddress));

                _client = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
```

**Binding configuration:**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GateWayService_BasicHttpbinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:05:00" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
            <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="65536" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>  
        </binding>
        <binding name="GateWayServiceEndPoint" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyContract" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

When we are trying to consume exposed methods for example,  `_client.SayHelloWorld();`

(407) Proxy Authentication Required is being thrown.

Why the WCF client is not using the default proxy settings?

*If we change connection settings Option -> settings -> connection settings to Auto detect proxy settings, it's working.*

Comment: What is the question? Why you need to use Auto detect proxy?

Comment: @jimmy - With useDefaultWebProxy="true" , it's not working. If Auto detect proxy = true, it's connecting. The question is, why it's not using default proxy settings if Auto detect proxy  = false.

Comment: My guess is that useDeafultWebProxy is not smart enough to handle anything other than a simple proxy address and your company is using something more sophisticated.

Comment: @jimmy - Thanks for the reply. Any other options to handle this scenario?